# Vagrant source value from environmental variable

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am setting up a vagrant deployment with aws as the backend. I would like to source values from the shell. For instance

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "dummy"

  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = "YOUR KEY"
    aws.secret_access_key = "YOUR SECRET KEY"
    aws.session_token = "SESSION TOKEN"
    aws.keypair_name = "KEYPAIR NAME"

    aws.ami = "ami-7747d01e"

    override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
    override.ssh.private_key_path = "PATH TO YOUR PRIVATE KEY"
  end
end
```

I would like to populate the aws.{access_key_id,secret_access_key,etc} values from local environmental variables in BASH (e.g. $access_key_id, $secret_access_key, etc).

Is this possible to do directly in ruby or is there a specific vagrant DSL technique that allows for this?

Comment: Also reading these from a file would be satisfactory. My objective is to decouple access credentials from static files in a repository, which I can do using file reads to populate parameters from file ignored by git.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are exposed via the `ENV` hash, whose keys are environment variable names. For example,

```
aws.access_key_id = ENV['access_key_id']
```